# Using AMQP with graphite 9.9

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, graphite

I'm attempting to connect RabbitMQ to Graphite using AMQP that is built into Graphite. However when I uncomment the setting in `carbon.conf` I get:

```
notroot@ubuntu:/opt/graphite/bin$ sudo python carbon-cache.py start
Starting carbon-cache (instance a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "carbon-cache.py", line 30, in <module>
    run_twistd_plugin(__file__)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/util.py", line 92, in run_twistd_plugin
    runApp(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 23, in runApp
    _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 386, in run
    self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 446, in createOrGetApplication
    ser = plg.makeService(self.config.subOptions)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/twisted/plugins/carbon_cache_plugin.py", line 21, in makeService
    return service.createCacheService(options)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/service.py", line 115, in createCacheService
    root_service = createBaseService(config)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/service.py", line 50, in createBaseService
    from carbon import amqp_listener
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/amqp_listener.py", line 29, in <module>
    from txamqp.protocol import AMQClient
ImportError: No module named txamqp.protocol
```

Answer (score 6):

pip install txamqp

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/txAMQP

because there is no real implementation of amqp in graphite carbon
it uses txamqp

Comment: If on Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install python-txamqp` works wonders too.